# laravel collection merge didn't work as I expected

Tags: laravel, collections

I have similar but slightly different Eloquent Model classes named `Exam`, `Type`, `Custom`.

```
  $recent = Exam::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
  $recent = $recent->merge(Type::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->take(3)->get());
  $recent = $recent->merge(Custom::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->take(3)->get());
```

Above is what I've tried and it doesn't work. Final `$recent` collection contains `Custom` items only. Other items like `Exam`, `Type` are disappeared.

Currently, I'm replace this part with `push` method. It works fine but even after saw the source code of `merge` method, I cannot find the reason why my previous code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your keys are almost similar (as you mentioned in the question). Values of string keys from the original collection will be replaced by the new collection values if key matches. So `merge` is not a better approach if you want values from three different models having same keys. Like same `id` from `Exam` model will be replaced by the `Type` model `id` and then it will be replaced by the `Custom` model `id`. `push` is ok as it doesn't replace the matched key values rather push it as a new item in the collection. So use `push` instead of `merge`

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-merge)

Comment: Have you tried this? I copy paste OP's question and am unable to reproduce

Comment: Thanks to your kind answer. Now I understand why my previous code doesn't work.

Comment: @CaddyDZ ya i have tested it before.